# What is the proper way to use codecs' encoding in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, decode, codec

I have an HTML file encoded in utf-8. I want to ouput it to a text file, encoded in utf-8. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import codecs
IN = codecs.open("E2P3.html","r",encoding="utf-8")
codehtml = IN.read()

#codehtml = codehtml.decode("utf-8") 

texte = re.sub("<br>","\n",codehtml)

#texte = texte.encode("utf-8") 

OUT = codecs.open("E2P3.txt","w",encoding="utf-8")
OUT.write(texte)

IN.close()
OUT.close()
```

As you can see, I've tried using both 'decode' and 'codecs'. Neither of these work, my output text file defaults as Occidental (Windows-1252) and some entities become gibberish.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think that the output file is encoded as Windows-1252? Are you using an editor that can't detect a UTF-8 file without a BOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a UTF-8 file with the `codecs` module, as you did, the contents of the file are automatically decoded into Unicode strings, so you must not try to decode them again.

The same is true when writing the file; if you write it using the `codecs` module, the Unicode string you're passing will automatically be encoded to whatever encoding you specified.

To make it explicit that you're dealing with Unicode strings, it might be a better idea to use Unicode literals, as in

```
texte = re.sub(u"<br>", u"\n",codehtml)
```

although it doesn't really matter in this case (which could also be written as

```
texte = codehtml.replace(u"<br>", u"\n")
```

since you're not actually using a regular expression).

If the application doesn't recognize the UTF-8 file, it might help saving it with a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (which is generally discouraged, but if the application can't recognize a UTF-8 file otherwise, it's worth a try):

```
OUT = codecs.open("E2P3.txt","w",encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Comment: The problem I have isn't with the re module, though.
The text contains characters such as ’ (or U+2019 in Unicode), and these characters become 'â€™' once I open the text file with other applications.
So this means that the codecs module does not, actually, encode my file in utf-8. I just don't understand why.

Comment: `â€™` *is*  UTF-8 for U+2019! If you see these characters, it means that whatever editor you're using thinks it's reading a Windows-1252 file. The editor is wrong, not the file.

Comment: Oh. Well that explains a lot then! I'm supposed to use that text file with a text analysis program (not a text editor), so the problem probably comes from _that_ program. I think I'll just replace or delete these entities, then. Thanks for your help!